# Which spices are best fried in oil, which are best toasted and which are best cooked in water?

Tags: spices

I've been learning a bit about spices and experimenting a little with dry toasting and frying spices rather than just adding them all to the water component. I keep reading that some spices go best in the water component, like saffron and nutmeg, but I can't really find anything with much more detail than that. Does a list exist of how the flavour profile of each of the common spices will be changed at the end of a dish when cooked in each manner?

Thank you :)

Comment: Sorry this question is too broad. There are hundreds of spices (generally, asking for a list of things on SE sites is considered too broad)

Comment: I mean, i'm really just looking for any sources on how the flavour profile of particular spices changes with the different cooking methods. It doesn't have to be an exhaustive list of every single spice..

Answer (score 1):

Generally? whole woody pieces such as star anise and cloves fry nicely. tiny dry leaves like oregano and marjoram with less success.

If a brief rub in the fingers disintegrates and releases a lot of aroma, water is best bet. Rule of Thumb

Comment: oh, toasting ground spice is for hard seeds like coriander, cumin, caraway but not ground roots and fruits -paprika tumeric-